# API that not exposes business Logic

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to write a WCF services that bring data to reporting tool.
Reporting tool presents data in lazy way, till user not clicked it's not showing the data.

I cannot send everything in once because there can be several megabits of data and because of that I need to send it in portions.

The problem is that I don't want to create a lot of  web functions for each report , because this way part of the BL will be in the reporting tool.

Is it possible somehow to make each report run in it's own web session and each time it's asks a next portion of data I will be able to send it back and everything made in the same session?

May be you have better solution to my problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of technologies that could help.  I would take a look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) which allow you to do flexible querying (IQuerable) and association traversal which should take care of your lazy loading concerns without having to create a whole load of seperate WCF calls.

Also take a look at [SQl Server Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx) which is a more general reporting solution that may appeal to you.

Either of these technologies should help you avoid your BL leaking into your reporting tool.  There are probably a whole host of similar non-MS solutions that do similar things, but I have listed the two above as your are using WCF, so you are probably more familiar with the MS stack (but maybe that was a silly assumption by me...if thats not the case they will get you started on what to look for!)